# c# create a new list from existing array of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following array of object.

```
"result": [
    {
        “maxTry: 17,
        "minTry”: 10,
        "details": [
            {
                “firstName”: “Sam”,
            },
            {
                "firstName”: ”Julio”,
            }
        ],
        "aggr": [
            “Abc”,
        ],
        "zone": “D3”
    },
    {
        "aggr": [
            "Abc",
        ],
        "zone": “C3”
    },
    {
        "aggr": [
            "Abc",
        ],
        "zone": “B2”
    },
    {
        "aggr": [
            "Abc",
        ],
        "zone": “T1”
    },
]
```

}

I want to create a new list out of the above object. The new list will first check if either `maxTry` or `minTry` node exists in an object. Only if both `maxTry` and `minTry` does not exist in an object, then add `zone` to the new list array. The new list will look something like this.

```
["C3", "B2", "T1"]
```

Comment: Deserialize the json and loop thru the collection and write logic with if and else in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define structure of the `JSON` object.
2. Deserialize `JSON` string into object.
3. Filter by your conditions.
4. Output the result.

You can replace the `record` definition as `class`, if your C# version is not very new, the code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

class Program
{
    public record JsonObject(Result[] Result);
    public record Detail(string FirstName);
    public record Result(int? MaxTry, int? MinTry, Detail[] Details, string[] Aggr, string Zone);

    public static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        var option = new JsonSerializerOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        var jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(Json, option);
        var newList = jsonObject.Result.Where(x => !x.MaxTry.HasValue && !x.MinTry.HasValue).Select(x => x.Zone).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", newList));
    }

    private static string Json = @"{""result"": [
    {
        ""maxTry"": 17,
        ""minTry"": 10,
        ""details"": [
            {
                ""firstName"": ""Sam"",
            },
            {
                ""firstName"": ""Julio"",
            }
        ],
        ""aggr"": [
            ""Abc"",
        ],
        ""zone"": ""D3""
    },
    {
        ""aggr"": [
            ""Abc"",
        ],
        ""zone"": ""C3""
    },
    {
        ""aggr"": [
            ""Abc"",
        ],
        ""zone"": ""B2""
    },
    {
        ""aggr"": [
            ""Abc"",
        ],
        ""zone"": ""T1""
    },
]}";
}
```

[image]